# Dropdownlist for with Dictionary<string,string> is not working with selected value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to bind a dropdown in MVC3 in this way.

Model

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> SexPreference()
{
      var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      dict.Add("Straight", "S");
      dict.Add("Gay", "G");
      dict.Add("Bisexual", "BISEX");
      dict.Add("Bicurious", "BICUR");
      return dict;
}
```

Controller

```
ViewBag.SexPreference = MemberHandler.SexPreference();
```

View

```
@{
var itemsSexPreference = new SelectList(ViewBag.SexPreference, "Value", "Key", Model.sexpreference);
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.sexpreference, @itemsSexPreference)
```

Dropdown is not selecting the selected value, don't know why.

Answer (score 29):

Why are you setting `ViewBag.SexPreference` when you have a model? Forget about this ViewBag. Also you should have 2 properties in order to make a dropdown list: a scalar type property to hold the selected value and a collection property to hold the list of selected values. Right now you seem to be using only one and attempting to bind the DropDown to a collection property which obviously doesn't make any sense.

Do it the right way, by using a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedSexPreference { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> SexPreferences { get; set; }
}
```

that you would populate in your controller action and pass to the view:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();

    // Set the value that you want to be preselected
    model.SelectedSexPreference = "S";

    // bind the available values
    model.SexPreferences = MemberHandler.SexPreference();

    return View(model);
}
```

and inside your view:

```
@model MyViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.SelectedSexPreference, 
    new SelectList(Model.SexPreferences, "Value", "Key")
)
```

Comment: model.sexpreference is string not collection.

Comment: problem is not in binding the dropdown. problem is in selected value.

Comment: That's because in your ViewBag you have put a collection with the same name as the string value in your model. If you want to go against best practices and not use a view model as I suggested you could still make it work but you need to rename your ViewBag parameter so that it is not conflicting with your string property name: `ViewBag.AvailableSexPreferences = MemberHandler.SexPreference();`. And then inside the view: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.sexpreference, new SelectList(ViewBag.AvailableSexPreferences, "Value", "Key"))`. But once again this is not a solution I would recommend.

Comment: Just tried your recommended solution but still with the same problem.

Comment: What about: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSexPreference, new SelectList(Model.SexPreferences, "Value", "Key", Model.SelectedSexPreference))`?

Comment: It added the selected value in drodownlist at the top. What's wrong i am doing?

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem. You could set the selected value to anything. For example `model.SelectedSexPreference = "BISEX";` should preselect a different item.

Comment: Already tried, but didn't work. But good news is that, after renaming to the ViewBag variable, its working now. But it should also work in your recommended way.

Answer (score 1):

Model.sexpreference must be one of these values: Straight...
This will Work:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> SexPreference()
{
  var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  dict.Add("S", "Straight");
  dict.Add("G", "Gay");
  dict.Add("BISEX", "Bisexual");
  dict.Add("BICUR", "Bicurious");
  return dict;
}

@{
    var itemsSexPreference = new SelectList(ViewBag.SexPreference, "Key", "Value", "S");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it differently. It's very frustrating this whole thing.

In the controller do something like:

```
var percentagesFromDb = _service1.GetPercentagesFromDb(parameters);
var percentages = percentagesFromDb.ToDictionary(percentage => percentage.someKey, 
                                                percentage => percentage.someValue);
ViewData["selectedPercentages"] = percentages;
```

And then in the model:

```
[Display(Name = "%")]
public string Percentage { get; set; }

private static Dictionary<string, string> GetPercentageList()
{
    return new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"100", "100%"},
        {"90", "90%"},
        {"80", "80%"},
        {"70", "70%"},
        {"60", "60%"},
        {"50", "50%"},
        {"40", "40%"},
        {"30", "30%"},
        {"20", "20%"},
        {"10", "10%"}
    };
}

public SelectList GetSelectList(string selected, object selectedPercentages)
{
    var selectedDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    if (selectedPercentages != null)
        selectedDict = (Dictionary < string, string>) selectedPercentages;
    var selectedvalue = selectedDict.ContainsKey(selected) ? selectedDict[selected] : "100";
    Percentage = selectedvalue;
    return new SelectList(GetPercentageList(), "Key", "Value");
}
```

And then finally in the view:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Items, new {@class = "control-label"})</th>
        <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Percentage, new {@class = "control-label"})</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Value
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Percentage,
                Model.GetSelectList(item.Key, ViewData["selectedPercentages"]),
                new {@class = "form-control", id = item.Key})
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 @* @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.GetAttribute_ID, new SelectList(Model.GetAttributes, "ID", "AttributeName", Model.GetAttribute_ID), "Select Attribute", new Dictionary<string, object>() { }) new { @id = "SelectAttribute", @name = "SelectAttribute[]", @class = "form-control dd" })*@
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.GetAttribute_ID, new SelectList(Model.GetAttributes, "ID", "AttributeName", Model.GetAttribute_ID), "Select Attribute", new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "class", "skill-level" }, { "data-val", "true" }, { "data-val-required", "Select skill level!"}})
```

Comment: I can't believe this f*ck*** attribute is necessary: "Model.GetAttribute_ID", thanks!!!